# chat module DataSnapshot from firebase not retrieving data in ListView

Tags: android, listview, firebase, chat

I'm trying to build a **simple chat activity** in side my app where all the requirements needed are in one place, the adapter, the attributes class, the viewholder class and the main activity are all to gather, at this point the activity sends one string line to firebase with no problem at all, but the code for data fetching is not working  , I'm using the **ChildEeventListiner** to receive one single string line in the listview, ((((( **my guess the DataSnapShot is not receiving any data** )))))
PS: I've used the same code in the same app but holding more complex data and works fine, I'm not sure what is missing here, hope somebody can figure out what wrong here, ask me if there is any additional data u need.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


//---------------------attributes Class ==> 1 string input-------------------

public class classChat  {

    String messageInPut;

    public classChat(String messageInPut) {
        this.messageInPut = messageInPut;


    }

    public String getMessageInPut() {
        return messageInPut;
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

FirebaseUser user;
DatabaseReference databaseChatView;
String msg;
classChat chats;
public static chatAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<classChat> bidChatdata;
ListView chatinstnc;
ImageView sendButton;
EditText messageArea;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    databaseChatView = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chat");

    chatinstnc = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatinstnc);
    sendButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    messageArea = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageArea);
    bidChatdata = new ArrayList<>();



  //------------------sending to firebase------------------------------------

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String messageId = databaseChatView.push().getKey();
            String msg = messageArea.getText().toString().trim();

            databaseChatView.child(messageId).setValue(msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "chat: "+ chats, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
   //--------------------List Item Click-------------------------------------

   /* chatinstnc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long messageId) {classChat dataModel = bidChatdata.get(position);}
    });*/

    //-------------Receiving Data From Firebase------------------------------

    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            bidChatdata.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                chats = chatSnapshot.getValue(classChat.class);
                bidChatdata.add(chats);
            }
            adapter = new chatAdapter(MainActivity.this, bidChatdata);
            chatinstnc.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            bidChatdata.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                chats  = chatSnapshot.getValue(classChat.class);
                bidChatdata.add(chats);
            }
            adapter = new chatAdapter(MainActivity.this, bidChatdata);
            chatinstnc.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    databaseChatView.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);



}


   //---------------adapter class--------------------------------------------

public class chatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<classChat>{
    ArrayList<classChat> chat;
    Context Context;

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView msg1;
    }


    public chatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<classChat> chat) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view_items, chat);
        this.chat = chat;
        this.Context = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final classChat chatdata = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        final View result;


        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_items, parent, false);
            viewHolder.msg1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.msg1);

            result = convertView;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }
        viewHolder.msg1.setText(chatdata.getMessageInPut());
        return convertView;
    }
}




}
```

Comment: Try printing the chatSnapshot.getValue to log without the classChat.class

Comment: u mean u want me to use a String Class ?

Comment: ok I removed the whole classChat and replaced it with String class and it worked fine receiving data I thank you for that :), but still I don't under stand why the classChat was causing such trouble  ?